# Function not importing properly

Tags: python

I am **teaching myself** Python through MIT's OCW for 6.00. (So please don't comment along the lines of "You shouldn't be asking for homework questions"... I'm not even at MIT, as much as I would love to be.) I'm currently stuck on [Problem #3 in Problem Set #5](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/assignments/pset5.pdf).

Here's the (relevant) part of `ps5.py`:

```
def update_hand(hand, word):
    """
    Uses up all the letters in the given word and returns
    the new hand. Does not modify hand.

    word: string
    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    """
    hand = hand.copy()
    for char in word:
        hand[char] = hand.get(char,0)-1
    return hand

def is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
    """
    Returns True if word is in the word_list and is entirely
    composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.
    Does not mutate hand or word_list.

    word: string
    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    word_list: list of lowercase strings
    """
    if word not in word_list:
        return False
    after = update_hand(hand.copy(),word)
    for char in after:
        if after[char] < 0:
            return False
    return True
```

I ran the code and it returns the correct result.

```
Loading word list from file...
   83667 words loaded.
play_game not implemented.
play_hand not implemented.
>>> word = "python"
>>> hand = {'h':1,'n':1,'o':1,'p':1,'t':1,'y':1}
>>> word_list = load_words()
Loading word list from file...
   83667 words loaded.
>>> is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list)
True
>>> word = "cobra"
>>> is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list)
False
>>> hand
{'h': 1,'n': 1,'o': 1,'p': 1,'t': 1,'y': 1}
```

My problem is that, when the `is_valid_word` function gets imported to `test_ps5.py`, it seems to simply return `False` for everything, which means it fails half of the test cases.

Here's the (relevant) part of `test_ps5.py`:

```
from ps5 import *

def test_is_valid_word(word_list):
    """
    Unit test for is_valid_word
    """
    failure=False
    # test 1
    word = "hello"
    hand = {'h':1, 'e':1, 'l':2, 'o':1}
    if not is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
        print "FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()"
        print "\tExpected True, but got False for word: '" + word + "' and hand:", hand
        failure = True
    # test 2 passes
    # test 3
    hand = {'n': 1, 'h': 1, 'o': 1, 'y': 1, 'd':1, 'w':1, 'e': 2}
    word = "honey"
    if  not is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
        print "FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()"
        print "\tExpected True, but got False for word: '"+ word +"' and hand:", hand
        failure = True
    # test 4 passes
    # test 5
    hand = {'e':1, 'v':2, 'n':1, 'i':1, 'l':2}
    word = "evil"
    if  not is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
        print "FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()"
        print "\tExpected True, but got False for word: '" + word + "' and hand:", hand
        failure = True
    # test 6 passes
    if not failure:
        print "SUCCESS: test_is_valid_word()"

word_list = load_words()
```

And here's the result when I run the code:

```
Loading word list from file...
   83667 words loaded.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing get_word_score...
SUCCESS: test_get_word_score()
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing update_hand...
SUCCESS: test_update_hand()
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Testing is_valid_word...
FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()
    Expected True, but got False for word: 'hello' and hand: {'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()
    Expected True, but got False for word: 'honey' and hand: {'e': 2, 'd': 1, 'h': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'w': 1, 'y': 1}
FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()
    Expected True, but got False for word: 'evil' and hand: {'i': 1, 'n': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'v': 2}
----------------------------------------------------------------------
All done!
```

I cannot understand what's causing the problem where and why.

Comment: Is ps5.py the code you wrote? Maybe put some print statements in your loops to help debug what precisely is going on and where it is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried it with the test vectors it's actually using?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Yes, I have tried each and every one of the test vectors. They work like they should in `ps5.py`.

Comment: Instead of pasting screenshots of your IDLE sessions, can you just copy and paste the text? It's a lot easier to read (and it also means people can copy and paste from it if that's useful, although that doesn't seem likely to matter in this case).

Comment: @audiodude - Yes, I did write the code for `ps5.py`. The `update_hand` function was Problem #2 for this problem set so I already made sure that works properly. The other `for` loop also works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code you posted. This works fine:

`ps5.py`:

```
def update_hand(hand, word):
    """
    Uses up all the letters in the given word and returns
    the new hand. Does not modify hand.

    word: string
    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    """
    hand = hand.copy()
    for char in word:
        hand[char] = hand.get(char,0)-1
    return hand

def is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
    """
    Returns True if word is in the word_list and is entirely
    composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.
    Does not mutate hand or word_list.

    word: string
    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    word_list: list of lowercase strings
    """
    if word not in word_list:
        return False
    after = update_hand(hand.copy(),word)
    for char in after:
        if after[char] < 0:
            return False
    return True
```

`words.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from ps5 import *

def test_is_valid_word(word_list):
    """
    Unit test for is_valid_word
    """
    failure=False
    # test 1
    word = "hello"
    hand = {'h':1, 'e':1, 'l':2, 'o':1}
    if not is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
        print "FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()"
        print "\tExpected True, but got False for word: '" + word + "' and hand:", hand
        failure = True
    # test 2 passes
    # test 3
    hand = {'n': 1, 'h': 1, 'o': 1, 'y': 1, 'd':1, 'w':1, 'e': 2}
    word = "honey"
    if  not is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
        print "FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()"
        print "\tExpected True, but got False for word: '"+ word +"' and hand:", hand
        failure = True
    # test 4 passes
    # test 5
    hand = {'e':1, 'v':2, 'n':1, 'i':1, 'l':2}
    word = "evil"
    if  not is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
        print "FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()"
        print "\tExpected True, but got False for word: '" + word + "' and hand:", hand
        failure = True
    # test 6 passes
    if not failure:
        print "SUCCESS: test_is_valid_word()"


def main():
    wordlist = ['honey', 'evil', 'python', 'dogs', 'weasels', 'hello']
    test_is_valid_word(wordlist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With both files in the same directory, here's the output:

```
paul@local:~/Documents/src/sandbox$ ./words.py
SUCCESS: test_is_valid_word()
paul@local:~/Documents/src/sandbox$
```

You imply several times that you're leaving out a lot of "irrelevant" code. With the exception of loading the word list from the file, none of that code appears to be needed for this problem. The issue must be somewhere in the code you're not showing. Since it doesn't seem to be needed for this problem, I'd suggest either (a) getting rid of it all; (b) getting rid of it piece by piece until your problem is fixed, and then incrementally adding back in and regularly testing, so you can see exactly what bit of code causes it to break; or (c) just inserting plenty of `print` statements at strategic places in your current code so you can see exactly where and why it's failing, which will give you a clue as to what's going on and help you isolate which bit of the code is causing the problem.

You also don't show how you're calling `test_is_valid_word()`, so it could be a simple problem with that.

`from something import *` is also generally a bad idea, and can sometimes cause mysterious problems resulting from namespace pollution. Try `from ps5 import update_hand, is_valid_word` instead, and see if that helps.

Without the rest of the code (which, again, seems not relevant anyway) you're the only person who can do any of these things.